# How do I make two functions share a variable?

Tags: python, try-except

My assignment is to make a secret number, which is 26, and make a guessing game saying the guess is either "too low" or "too high". I made two functions, int_guess for if the input is an integer and not_int_guess for when the input is not an integer. The problem that i have though is when im counting the amount of guesses, i dont know how to make both functions share a count of how many guesses they inputted.

```
print("Guess the secret number! Hint: it's an integer between 1 and 100...")
secret_num = 26
guess = int(input("What is your guess? "))
def int_guess(guess):
    count = 0
    while guess != 26:
        if guess > secret_num:
            print("Too high!")
            guess = int(input("What is your guess? "))
            count += 1
        elif guess < secret_num:
            print("Too low!")
            guess = int(input("What is your guess? "))
            count += 1
    else:
        print("You guessed it! It took you", count, "guesses.")
def not_int_guess(guess,count):
    print("Bad input! Try again: ")
    guess = int(input("What is your guess? "))
    while guess != 26:
        if guess > secret_num:
            print("Too high!")
            guess = int(input("What is your guess? "))
        elif guess < secret_num:
            print("Too low!")
            guess = int(input("What is your guess? "))
        else:
            print("You guessed it! It took you", count, "guesses.")
try:
    int_guess(guess)
except:
    not_int_guess(guess,count)
```

One part of the assignment that i need to have is a try and except, the problem is that the count will reset to zero if the except is used, but i need the count to carry over to the exception case. I tried carrying the "count" variable over to the not_int_guess by placing it like not_int_guess(guess,count) but that doesnt work for a reason i dont understand.

Comment: Check out the `global` statement in the Python docs.

Comment: Making two separate nearly-identical functions is a terrible way to solve this problem.  Collect input from the user and ensure that it is an integer as one step, then call the function as a second step.

Comment: Either use global variable, or make the function `int_guess` to output the `count` variable and pass it to not_int_guess. However, note that in your current implementation, if the number of guesses expire there will be no exception, thus your function not_int_guess will not be executed. You need an exit condition from the function `int_guess`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using two functions, use the try and except within the while loop. That way everything is much neater and more efficient (also good to define functions before any main code):

```
def int_guess(secret_num):
    count = 0
    guess = 0 #Just defining it here so everything in the function knows about it
    while guess != secret_num:
        try:
            guess = int(input("What is your guess? "))
        except ValueError as err:
            print("Not a number! Error:", err)
            continue #This will make the program skip anything underneath here!

        if guess > secret_num:
            print("Too high!")
            
        elif guess < secret_num:
            print("Too low!")

        count += 1 #Adds to count

    #This will run after the while loop finishes:
    print("You guessed it! It took you", count, "guesses.") 


#Main code:

print("Guess the secret number! Hint: it's an integer between 1 and 100...")
int_guess(26)
```

Like this, the function will run until the user has guessed the number no matter what they input, while also keeping count through any errors

Comment: 1.) no need for two lines with `count += 1`. Place it below `if ... elif` and the code will become one line shorter. 2.) Using `except`without listing which exception ( `ValueError` ) it should catch is usually considered bad practice. Better is to use `except ValueError:`

Comment: Yes very true, I will edit it to include this

Comment: ... and don't forget to change `26` in the function while loop to `secret_num` ... To avoid confusion best use `int_guess(26)` .

Comment: Ok, I won't include the correct way to run the function using `if __name__ == '__main__':` for the sake of simplicity though

Answer (score 0):

You can use the count variable outside the functions to use it in both the variables globally.

I have also made some changes to the code to make it work properly

```
print("Guess the secret number! Hint: it's an integer between 1 and  100...")
secret_num = 26
count = 0
guess = 0
def int_guess(guess):
   count = 0
   while guess != 26:
       guess = int(input("What is your guess? "))
       if guess > secret_num:
           print("Too high!")
           count += 1
       elif guess < secret_num:
           print("Too low!")
           count += 1
    else:
       print("You guessed it! It took you", count, "guesses.")
def not_int_guess(guess):
    print("Bad input! Try again: ")
    int_guess(guess)

try:
    int_guess(guess)
except:
    not_int_guess(guess)
```

Comment: Have you tested your code before posting it here? It does *not* work properly (having multiple issues). It's not helpful to post bad code ...